# UITableViewCell textLabel overwrites my button

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

Probably a simple question, but I can't find the answer.
When I set my textLabel it overwrites my Detail Disclosure button that I have in my content view of the cell, put in through the storyboard. Now it only shows when the cell is selected. My code looks like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"accountCell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

User *user = [arr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

// Configure the cell...
cell.textLabel.text = [user username];

return cell;
}
```

When I take away cell.textLabel.text = [user username]; it shows all the time, as I want.
Any tips? Guess I gotta put some code in for my button...

Comment: Try with adding if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    } code below UITableViewCell *cell  code.

Comment: Nope, no success. I think the problem lies within the textLabel that is put over somehow. I guess it's some constrains problem, but dunno.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out...

To understand this question, you need to understand that a UITableViewCell only has three spaces - imageView, textLabel and accessory. When you set the textLabel it overwrites everything you've created in the content area in storyboard. I had to set a a new class, with subclass UITableViewCell and set the custom IBOutlets in that one, then link in the custom class to my TableView.

Comment: It doesn't overwrite anything. The textLabel just takes up the entire contentView. Your button is still there behind textLabel. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH7-SW10